# Stored procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure; when I try to execute I get an error message which is related to `BIGINT` datatype, can you please assist me where I am doing wrong here.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Invalid] 
    @AccountNumber NVARCHAR(30) = NULL,
    @RoutingNumber NVARCHAR(9) = NULL,
    @PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(30) = NULL,
    @ReturnCode NVARCHAR(3) = NULL,
    @Return BIGINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @ReturnCode = '' 
        SET @ReturnCode = NULL 

    SET @Return = 0

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Invalid 
               WHERE (((@AccountNumber IS NULL AND AccountNumber IS NULL) OR AccountNumber = @AccountNumber))                
    BEGIN  
        SET @DataExists = 1  
    END    
              
    -- If same record already exists - return -1
    IF (@DataExists = 1) 
        RETURN -1
    ELSE
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO dbo.Invalid(AccountNumber, RoutingNumber, ReturnReasonCode,
                                PolicyNumber, LastUpdatedDate, ExpiryDate)
        VALUES (@AccountNumber, @RoutingNumber, @ReturnCode,
                @PolicyNumber, GETDATE(), GETDATE())

        RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END                                      
END
```

This is how I try to call it in SQL Server:

```sql
DECLARE @count BIGINT;

EXEC usp_Invalid
         @AccountNumber = '848784', 
         @RoutingNumber='896789', 
         @PolicyNumber='1000808919', 
         @Return = @count OUTPUT;

SELECT @count
```

When I verify the `RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()` value - I am able to see the value like this - 10000000000054

Error message:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_Invalid
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. The 'usp_Invalid' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.

Comment: You are trying to `RETURN` the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, and when your `INSERT` fails (due to the error you got), then `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` has a value of `NULL`, and thus an error occurs when you try to `RETURN` its value (`NULL`). `RETURN`, however, is meant for the success status of a procedure, `0` for success, anything else for failure. Use an `OUTPUT` parameter to return the value of the inserted `IDENTITY` to the calling SQL *not* `RETURN`.

Comment: `SET @Return = SCOPE_IDENTITY();`

Comment: Thank you for the response, actually I am able to see that data is successfully getting inserted , however when RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY() - line executed - it throws an error message.

Comment: @user17824023 Read the comments above.  It'll fix your problem.

Comment: so you are trying to say that, instead of returning direct SCOPE_IDENTITY(), just follow the below lines correct :- SET @@Return = SCOPE_IDENTITY() Return @@Return. Here @@ means single @ only

Comment: No.  Don't use the `RETURN` statement unless you mean to affect the _*exit code*_ of your proc.  Just use `SET @Return = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` and be done.  You should review this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15  `RETURN` values are _vastly_ different than `OUTPUT` parameters

Comment: You're confusing output parameters with the value specified by `return <x>`

Comment: You also need to change `RETURN -1` to `SET @Return = -1;`.

Comment: Sure, just verified it worked, Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Note `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is data type numeric(38,0) whereas a stored proc return value is limited to int. As already mentioned, don't use the return code to return data; only success (zero) or failure (non-zero).